# Body onload injection: how to restore order sequence

Tags: javascript

I want to add an event listener to body onload and execute AFTER the existing one. But the execution is reverse. Why ? How to fix this ?

https://jsfiddle.net/0LcL1usj/

```
<html>
<script>
    function test() {
        alert('SHOULD BE FIRST');
    }
</script>

<script>
// Dean Edwards/Matthias Miller/John Resig

function init() {

// quit if this function has already been called
if (arguments.callee.done) return;

    alert("hello init");

// flag this function so we don't do the same thing twice
arguments.callee.done = true;

// kill the timer
if (_timer) clearInterval(_timer);

// do stuff
};

/* for Mozilla/Opera9 */
if (document.addEventListener) {
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
}

/* for Internet Explorer */
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_win32)
document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)><\/script>");
var script = document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == "complete") {
    init(); // call the onload handler
    }
};
/*@end @*/

/* for Safari */
if (/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // sniff
var _timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
    init(); // call the onload handler
    }
}, 10);
}

/* for other browsers */
window.onload = init;
</script>

<body onload="test();">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onload` event occurs *after* `DOMContentLoaded`:

- [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) fires when the entire DOM has been constructed,
- [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) fires when all the linked resources (fonts, images, scripts, iframes...) have loaded in addition.